# Does Google Cloud Run (or AWS Lambda) rely on container isolation or KVM?

Tags: docker, kvm

I was wondering if it is secure or not to run containers from different customers on the same machine. Basically I was investigating the level of isolation / security provided by Docker alone.

Then I found Google Cloud Run, and I was wondering which one of the following is true:

- **Does it relies only on Docker isolation and runs the containers of different customers on the same nodes?** In this case, the answer to my original question would be "yes, Docker container isolation is high, even Google relies on that"
- **Does it run Docker containers inside VM (created with KVM) and each VM is dedicated only to one specific customer?** In this case, the answer to my original question would be "no", but I would have also additional doubts (i.e. how does Google instantly creates/destroys an entire VM, for each single request... this seems an impossible job).

I think that the same question can be also applied to other server-less solutions like AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google cloud run makes use of gvisor (info [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/how-gvisor-protects-google-cloud-services-from-cve-2020-14386)), to provide it's container sandbox.

AWS Lambda makes use of firecracker (info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/firecracker-lightweight-virtualization-for-serverless-computing/)) for it's sandbox.

Whilst Docker with runc containers provides a reasonable level of isolation for many workloads (and can be further hardened from its default settings) both Google and Amazon are operating with arbitrary possibly malicious code and a threat model that includes high end attackers, so it makes sense for them to look at options which may provide a smaller attack surface and higher level of isolation than standard Linux containers.